# Understanding motivation provided for the definition of vector differentiability

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I’m having trouble following the steps of this proof regarding generalizing the limit definition of a derivative to apply to vectors. The part of the proof that most confuses me has been circled.

[image]

The author claims that the equation remains the same if we replace h with -h and g with -g, but I don't see how this is true. If h is replaced with -h shouldn't f'(x)h be negative? And why is ∣h∣g(h) not ∣hg(h)∣?

Comment: Josh, I took the liberty of changing your title to improve your chances at answers. Also, this isn't a proof so I removed the tags.

Answer (score 0):

Of course $hf'(x)$ may be positive, negative or zero.

In more detail, this is what's going on.
You have
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=hf'(x)+hg(h)$$
where $\lim_{h\to0}g(h)=0$. Define a function $g_1$ by
$$g_1(h)=\begin{cases}g(h)&\text{if } h>0,\\
0&\text{if }h=0,\\
-g(h)&\text{if }h<0.
\end{cases}$$
Then
$$f(x+h)-f(x)=hf'(x)+|h|g_1(h)$$
where $\lim_{h\to0}g_1(h)=0$.

Comment: But then isn't g not a function anymore, since it would have equal outputs for positive and negative inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is badly worded. But what they are trying to say we can define $g_1(h)=\frac h {|h|} g(h)$ for $h \neq 0$ ($0$ for $h=0$) to get $f(x+h)-f(x)=f'(x)h+|h|g_1(x)$ with $g_1(h) \to 0$ as $h \to 0$.

Comment: Ok, it makes a little more sense now, but what is the motivation for this selection? Why does hg(h) always need to be positive?

Comment: From the portion of the book you have quoted it is not at clear as to what the author is trying to achieve. @JoshAbel